# What does TriScatteredInterp in Matlab do?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand the `TriScatteredInterp` in Matlab.
I followed sample program in the help file.

```
x = rand(100,1)*4-2;
y = rand(100,1)*4-2;
z = x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2);   
Construct the interpolant:
F = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,z);
```

What I observe is F.X is same as x and y and F.V is same as z;

```
ti = -2:.25:2;
[qx,qy] = meshgrid(ti,ti);
qz = F(qx,qy);
```

I consider linear interpolation is done in the `qz = F(qx,qy);`. How does it do for the linear interpolation?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know if I understand you question - but `TriScatteredInterp` uses [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).

Comment: Yes Matlab uses Delaunay triangulation. Then how to do interpolation with grid data.

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand how TriScatteredInterp works in Matlab.
We have x,y,z points for N X 3 dimensions. 
All these points, we need to implement Delaunay triangles in C++. 
That is easy. Then, for all your desired grid points x', y', please search the triangle in which your x',y' is located. Then do Barycentric interpolation in a triangle as shown in the [link](http://cumbia.visus.uni-stuttgart.de/ger/research/proj/ito/materials/VIS-Slides-03-Interpolation_and_Filtering.pdf). You will get z' for these x',y'. That is all what we need to do in C++ for TriScatteredInterp. Good Luck!

Comment: Is this the answer to your question?